# Why is startActivity causing my app to crash?

Tags: android-studio, android-intent, start-activity

When the myincome button is clicked, my app crashes, and i'm not sure why. My manifest looks right to me. What is causing it to crash? Most other questions similar to mine were answered by missing to include the activity on the manifest, but mine is already on there. I appreciate any feedback.

StartingActivity:

```
public class StartingActivity extends AppCompatActivity
{
private TextView myincome;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_starting);

    myincome = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.myIncome);

    myincome.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v)
        {
            // Start DetailActivity
            Intent j = new Intent(StartingActivity.this, DetailActivity.class);
            startActivity(j);
        }
    });

}
}
```

DetailActivity:

```
public class DetailActivity extends AppCompatActivity
{

private TextView back;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_detail); //default

    back = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.back);

    //back button
    back.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v)
        {
            finish();
        }
    });
 }
```

Manifest:

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity
        android:name=".StartingActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".DetailActivity">
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".CategoriesActivity">
    </activity>
</application>
```

Comment: Post stack trace or error log from Android Studio instead of posting every single files from your application.

Answer (score 1):

Look at `Run` log. It must be said something like

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'setOnClickListener()' on a null object reference
```

pointing at line

```
myincome.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
```

So `myincome` is null because you didn't assign anything to it.

Comment: My apologies, 'myincome' is assigned a value, i must have deleted it on accident when i deleted other irrelevant variables in the onCreate method. Still crashes, without an error message

Comment: @Xenu neither Run nor Logcat doesn't show any errors?

Comment: none, which makes this more difficult to me. the app runs and just crashes upon clicking the button. 'Clean Project' and 'Rebuild Project' also don't fix this

Comment: @Xenu show full .java and .xml files for both activities

Comment: i'm showing everything now. 'Categories button intent works just fine. my problem is only with DetailActivity